# Is it better to ask related questions back-to-back or with some time between?

Tags: discussion

I asked two opposite questions related to insect repellent [back](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/are-deet-based-insect-repellents-effective-against-fleas) to [back](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/are-any-natural-insect-repellents-effective-against-fleas), and the wording caused the second to be confused as a duplicate with the first (one asking about DEET, one about DEET-free). I'm wondering if I should have waited a day or week between the questions to prevent it looking like a duplicate. Thoughts?

Comment: Nope, it's perfectly valid to ask questions back to back, providing they are different questions

Comment: I think the subtle differences in those questions could of been highlighted better, Use bold, say I've asked this question before but this one is different because, etc

Comment: Hi Liam. Would you be willing to turn your comments here into an answer? Since it's listed as having zero answers, both on the main page and in the "unanswered questions" list, people might not realize there's a really helpful answer that just happens to be in the comments. If you agree, I'd appreciate that. Then we can delete these comments and it will be a nice clean question and answer for future visitors to see! Thanks! :)